# Creating a program that sends a query "show slave status;" and compares the returned value to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need guidance and code examples to compare the Specific values returned from "show slave status" to a string every 5 minutes. And if the value doesn't match up it sends a query to restart.

This is what i have for now:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            BindData();

    }


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private DataTable dt;

    public void BindData()
    {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 127.0.0.1; user id = system; persistsecurityinfo = True; port = 3308; database = test1; Password = 975315");
            con.Open();


            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("show slave status;", con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adp.Fill(ds); //Fill Dataset
            dt = ds.Tables[0]; //Then assign table to dt
            ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "";
            GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();


        con.Close();
```

Comment: ok and specifically what issue are you facing with trying to implement what you want? What research have you done? What have you tried so far? You haven't actually asked us a question or described a problem. We're not here to just research and write all of it for you, but we will _help_ you with any difficulties you're facing. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where to start, if someone can show me how to do (if "Slave_IO_Running" = no) then send a specific query.

Comment: we don't do generic examples or tutorials here. If you don't know where to start then it indicates that you probably haven't done enough basic research and/or spent enough thinking time. We're not going to do that research on your behalf.

Comment: Anyway, here's a hint: Since you have read the values from the query into a DataTable (within a DataSet), then you just need to loop through the rows in the DataTable and examine the contents of each cell (or, if you know which cell will contain the interesting info, then you can just target that cell specifically instead). You can use an `if` statement to compare the value in the cell to the result you're interested in. And then if there's a problem, you can start a new MySqlCommand to issue a new query to the database. All of those bits are common tasks and very easy to google.

Comment: Thanks but there are no good examples on the internet i can use to reference.

Comment: sorry but that's just not true. What have you actually been searching for? Break the process down into steps, like I described. Each step is easy to research. [Here are some google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+read+from+datatable&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=C%23+read+from+datatable&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i58j0l4.5293j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for the first step (reading the data from the datatable). You're going to tell me there's nothing you can learn from any of those results?? I think either you're searching for nonsense or you aren't even trying.